# Informing colleagues about lavatory etiquette?

Tags: professionalism, india, training

This is a small company in India which has engineers, finance professionals, janitors and even interns from abroad, working there.

The founders noticed that many employees aren't very familiar with lavatory etiquette and ensuring hygiene, and they wished to conduct a small training to inform employees about it.

Since this is a slightly touchy issue, they aren't sure how to proceed. An [online search](https://www.alsco.com.au/2015/02/workplace-bathroom-etiquette-keeps-workmates-happier-safer/) showed [some pages](https://worksmart.org.uk/health-advice/where-you-work/toilets-and-washrooms) which had requisite info, but do not speak about how to proceed with educating employees about it.

Would it be too in-your-face or insulting if a small training session was conducted about this where everyone is invited?

Is there a better way to proceed with this?

Comment: I don't know about "better" but angry signs with "don't pee on the floor" and "your mother doesn't clean up after you here" are a staple in many places where this is a problem. At least it avoids being "in your face" by putting the signs close to the crime scene.

Comment: If you post sign(s), don't make them angry; make the message a matter-of-fact reminder "Employees must wash hands before returning to work" or perhaps include light humor if feasible.

Comment: What type of sign/humour to use may also be culturally different. An example from Germany may be found by searching for "Toilettenbürstenbenutzungsanweisung", but I wouldn't assume that example would translate well to another culture.

Comment: we have 'standard operating procedures' (witten instructions) here at my work, these are often printed out and displayed next to where the operation is done, we also have one over the toilet, written instructions on how it's expected to be used

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of etiquette isn't being followed. Do people try to open stall doors when they're locked by turning via the little slot on the outside? Are the guy's aim poor? Do people yap on the phone in the bathroom? Is it a simple failure to wash hands? I would think these situations would all require different answers. (I get the last 3 in my office in the US and have seriously though about putting up those "angry" signs since people from different departments & different companies use the same bathroom...)

Comment: Whatever you do, people react much better when they are explained _why_ the rules are rather than just saying what they are.

Comment: Toilettenbürstenbenutzungsanweisung is a great word!

Comment: Founders "noticed".... ugh.

Comment: @tripleee I feel like I have never seen such signs achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Davidmh you really think people need it explained to them? For some reason they actually don't know ?

Comment: @Kilisi they aren't doing it, so obviously they either don't know it, or don't consider it as important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Would it be too in-your-face or insulting if a small training session was conducted about this where everyone is invited?

**No, it's just an information, and something the company wants to take care of.**

> Is there a better way to proceed with this?

The signs you put in the bathroom are commonly useless for the ones who know and already take care of their personal hygiene, and **helpful** (and not *helpless*, typo corrected thanks to @Brandin) for the ones who don't care and/or don't know.

In order to create awareness for the ones who don't know, it's always useful to show them the benefits of doing something. As a simple search (that you already did) can give many information (e.g. [diseases spread not washing hands](http://www.livestrong.com/article/90832-diseases-spread-not-washing-hands/), I think you could let people know what they face.

Before you set up a meeting, you can send an email, sharing data about the diseases than can be spread. Or just say nothing, call for the meeting, and explain. But it's important that people understand that the company does that not to bother them or to "educate" them, but to protect *everyone's health*, including the company (*less people calling off, better the rate of return, greater benefits for eveybody*).

Then, when everybody knows, put the signs. As a nice reminder.

Don't put the blame on anyone, show them why it's good for them, AND everyone around them, and they will be more willing to listen to you. **Create awareness for the ones who don't know**.

Comment: "The signs you put in the bathroom are commonly useless..." Says who? At least one research seems to show promising results for signage (some may ignore them, but if you see the same sign every day...): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25603617

Comment: @Brandin : I agree, that's why I was careful and said *are commonly* (you know: useless, of course, because you already take care / don't know: helpful / everyday information). I thought it was clear, but I'm willing to improve if it's not what people understand from my phrase.

Comment: OMG! just saw the typo!!! sorry @Brandin, I wrote *helpless* instead of **helpful**, I understand why you wrote this comment, thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: In addition to this, I'd like to note that you should SET UP your bathroom for hygiene. If you are expected to wash your hands under the tap, but then have to shut the valve that you touched before with the same hands... Nobody will. Motion-sensitive taps are way better.

Comment: @WeckarE., Along the same lines, some workplaces have foot-pedal activated faucets and swinging doors to get out of the restroom that do not require you to touch the door handles to get out. Also, having a well stocked, regularly inspected, and pleasant bathroom to be in can go a long way. Showers and changing rooms can be helpful too if employees bike to work or work overtime.

Comment: What was eventually done was to have a small meeting where everyone was informed (which went well), but then a separate email was sent where everyone were told that one toilet is for foreigners. One toilet is for the founders and one for the staff and consultants. So in-spite of the "education", separate toilets were mandated anyway. Now **that** was insulting.

Comment: @Nav : *Now that was insulting* oops! agreed... IMO, folks went too far too quick, wow! Talk about escalate here :/

Answer (score 34):

The most common method (actually the only one I have seen) is to post signs. Either humorous picture ones or more bland ones from management just stating the expectations on hygiene and proper usage. Or a combination of both.

If it was an ongoing issue the best recourse would be a blanket email, either to staff or managers from someone up the hierarchy. Along the lines of "Your sections toilets are a disgusting mess, please make sure I don't see them in this condition again." more or less polite as suits the situation.

The manager could also bring it up in a staff meeting. It's not so much training or educating as reminding them to respect others and their workplace, most people already know that they're not supposed to pee/poo on the floor/seat/walls and don't do it at home. In the same way that they would reprimand staff who made a mess in the workspace.

Comment: Aye.  Post signs up.  Even in a Western based FTSE 100 company, we still have to educate people what bins are for and that cleaners don't wash the cubicles immediately after they've left it.

Comment: in 2012 Swansea University was highlighted in the press for putting up signs giving instructions for the use of toilets http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-south-west-wales-16983788 - interestingly they seem to be in English only rather than bi-lingual English/Welsh

Comment: I love the one from Google's office: http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2013/02/googler-wash-hands-code-1360068717.jpeg

Comment: "Wash hands" signs are commonplace. The worst offenders (and the question isn't specific) aren't going to pay attention to signs even if it calls them out by name.

Comment: @Rich nor will they pay attention to training etc,. some do it on purpose. You don't need to train adults how to wash their hands

Comment: "Nobody pissed on means nobody pissed off" :)

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be too in-your-face or insulting if a small training session
>   was conducted about this where everyone is invited?

No, it would not be too in your face, it **everyone** is required to attend.  Regardless of who you are, and what your position is, it is not unreasonable to expect when the time comes for the lavatory to be in a clean state.

> Is there a better way to proceed with this?

Besides *mandatory* training for all, I am not sure what else can be done.  Signs I think will be ignored for the most part, once the novelty wears off.

This article contains an email that was sent to everyone in the office.  I am not sure how well this will be received, as personalities differ, but I thought it may be of use to you.  From the article:

> Cleaning Up 
>   Treat the public restroom even better than the one at your
>   home. In a public restroom, flushing every time is considerate. If you
>   make a mess, use every effort to clean it up. The restroom should be
>   left in as good as or better condition after your use than it was
>   before you entered. Always wash your hands with soap after conducting
>   your business.

Entire article:  [software firm office wide bathroom etiquette email](http://abovethelaw.com/2012/02/san-francisco-firm-sends-awesome-officewide-restroom-etiquette-email/2/)

Comment: In this company they are planning to have a small powerpoint presentation meeting with all employees about the matter.

Comment: @Nav Take a look at the article.  The approach to the subject is spot on IMHO.  Sad that this has to happen, but if necessary, the article is a good resource for the presentation.